# Compare GCEUs to performance of physical machine (e.g. MacBook Pro)

Tags: performance, google-compute-engine

Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#gceu) states that a machine of type `g1-small` has 1.38 GCEUs (Google Compute Engine Units).

Is there a simple formula for calculating how this (roughly) compares to the performance of familiar physical machines, such as the laptop that I am using now: a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, late 2013)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be difficult to compare a given size Compute VM to a physical laptop. You have the usual problem of comparing a virtual machine to a physical one, and added complications due to how Compute VM's are hosted in the cloud, and instead of communicating with local disks, may be doing IO from other cloud infrastructure like Google Disks, cloud databases, GCS, etc.

The only description Google gives is at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#gceu. In my experience, all you can really do is get a feel for how some Compute VM's behave, compare them to each other, and monitor them to determine if/when they are CPU-bound, IO-bound, network-bound, etc. Google provides decent tools for this in their [Compute dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances).